# How To Add Custom Fields to Existing Views in Odoo 12 With Addons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I'm totally new to Odoo Add-ons (custom module) development and i'd like to know how can i possibly add a custom models to an existing views without creating a custom views to inherit it.

My goal is to create a Boolean and new field that will show in **product.template** as picture below :

[image]

but once i'm upgrading my custom module, it's says :

> Field "x_show_in_ecommerce" does not exist in model "product.template"

My models named **sempoaEcommerce.py**

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class SempoaEcommmerce(models.Model):
    _name = "sempoa.ecommerce"
    _description = "Sempoa Ecommerce"

    x_show_in_ecommerce = fields.Boolean()
    x_description_sale_ecommerce = fields.Text()
```

And here's my **sempoaEcommerce.xml** file

```
    <record id="product_template_only_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <field name="sale_ok" position="after">
                <field name="x_show_in_ecommerce"/>
                <field name="x_description_sale_ecommerce"/>
            </field>

        </field>
    </record>
```

I'm using Odoo 14 to develop this custom module.
Any advice and help is really, really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views define the way the records of a model are displayed, to display your field in a model form view you have to add the field to that model (`product.template`).

Alter the `product.template` model to add `x_show_in_ecommerce`  and  `x_description_sale_ecommerce` fields:

```py
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    x_show_in_ecommerce = fields.Boolean()
    x_description_sale_ecommerce = fields.Text()
```

`sale_ok` is defined inside a `div` and they defined its label manually, your two fields will be displayed without labels.

Comment: Thanks, worked really good. Also don't forget to restart both postgresql and odoo services.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that restarting only Odoo server is enough (No need to restart the PostgreSQL server)